# How to replace N/A with a rounded mean in R?

Tags: r, rounding, mean, na, missing-data

A participant did not enter their age, so I need to replace it with the mean, however I am unable to do this without it being replaced as a decimal. This is the code I have entered:

```
FirstDataSet_NoGaps <- FirstDataSet %>% mutate(Age= ifelse(is.na(Age), 
           mean(Age, na.rm = T), Age))
mean(FirstDataSet_NoGaps$Age)
```

For clarity. The entry for the participant who's age was missing now has the mean age in its place when I look at the dataset in the data table in the global environment, however this is as a decimal (it reads '22.26103').

How do I replace their missing age, with the mean age rounded to no decimal places, i.e. to make it show as '22' not '22.26103'?

I am very new to R, so I apologise if this seems trivial or poorly explained. Thank you

Comment: Wrap a `round` around your mean calculation: `round(mean(Age, na.rm = TRUE), 0)`.

Comment: The problem you will face is that a rounded numeric value will still display as `22.0000`. To get an answer that addresses your unstated needs, you need to say why you want to do this. (It's not going to be statistically valid.)